# Equals method not working well with Throwable

Tags: java, error-handling, equals

I have some externally provided callbacks to run. As they can contain anything, I prefer to risk catching `Throwable` upon them and therefore recovering from any errors that are recoverable.

Certain phases of callback executions are allowed to throw error unless the error repeats twice in a row. In that case, they are marked invalid and can no longer run unless user manually launches them.

This is the method meant to handle that:

```
  /**
   * Sets whether the bot is disabled due to error or not. If error has occured during 
   * getWindow, the bot will be disabled immediatelly. If the error occured during canRun() or run()
   * the bot will only be disabled if the error is repetitive.
   * @param error error that occured
   * @param phase phase of execution in which the error occured
   * @return true if this error is not significant enough to cancel this bot
   */
  public boolean continueOnError(Throwable error, ExecutionPhase phase) {
    System.err.println("Error "+error+" caught in robot "+this.getClass().getName());
    System.err.println("Last: "+lastError+((error.equals(lastError)?" which is the same as last":" which is defferent than last")));
    if(phase == ExecutionPhase.GET_WINDOW || (error.equals(lastError) && phase==errorPhase)) {
      //Remember last
      setLastError(error, phase);
      //If robot state listener is listening, inform it about this event
      if(listener!=null)
        listener.disabledByError(error);
      //Disable the robot - on attempt to run, it will throw RobotDisabledException
      return !(errorDisabled = true);
    }
    //Rememeber last
    setLastError(error, phase);
    //The robot can remain running, but next same error will turn it down
    return true;
  }
```

I understand this is a primitive approach but I need to start somewhere. The problem with this code is that the `equals` method on `Throwable` allways returns false. See the output generated by this method:

```
Error java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR caught in robot cz.autoclient.robots.LaunchBot
Last: java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR which is defferent than last
Error java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR caught in robot cz.autoclient.robots.LaunchBot
Last: java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR which is defferent than last
Error java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR caught in robot cz.autoclient.robots.LaunchBot
Last: java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR which is defferent than last
Error java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR caught in robot cz.autoclient.robots.LaunchBot
Last: java.lang.Error: TEST ERROR which is defferent than last
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: I am assuming `phase` is an `enum` here.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Throwable` doesn't override `Object`'s `equals`, so `error.equals(lastError)` behaves the same as `error == lastError`.

Perhaps it would be enough for you compare the classes :

```
error.getClass().equals(lastError.getClass())
```

Comment: So I'll have to figure something myself I guess.

Comment: And in fact, how _would_ it?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Comparing all the properties is a 100% sure way to go.

Comment: @TomášZato: No, it's not.

Comment: @TomášZato so an exception with the same message thrown from a different place is different? That would probably be a surprise to some people. The converse would be a surprise to others. Two exceptions separately thrown should always, I think, be different so `==` makes the most sense.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Why not? If all properties are equal, it's equal by definition. Come with a case where this does not apply please.

Comment: @TomášZato: My point is that it won't work in 100% of the cases since some properties (like a timestamp) of an exception might be different even when it's being thrown in the same place by the same code.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Yeah, exceptions in different time are different. Surelly, such `equals` method wouldn't help me too. But I don't think `Throwable` has timestamp property defined.

Comment: @TomášZato: My point is that you don't have control over the exception code. People can do weird things in there and your code needs to be able to handle it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It shouldn't surprise peopel since an excecption from "a different place" would have a different stacktrace so by definition their properties would differ

Answer (score 2):

`Throwable` doesn't *override*  `equals()`, there lies the problem Your `Error` and `LastError` instances might be 2 different `Throwable` instances with same value

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` doesn't work since it compares only the instance. If you throw the "same" exception twice, that gives you two instances and `Object.equals()` returns false for that.

There is no perfect way in Java to check whether two exceptions are the same (they might contain timestamps, for example).

A better approach is probably to remember the component which caused the problem and disable it when it starts to throw too many errors (no matter which ones or if they repeat).

Also `Throwable` captures non-recoverable `Error`s as well which you probably don't want. The code should work on `Exception` or maybe even `RuntimeException` instead, depending on how your design works.

Comment: As I said, `Throwable` includes non recoverable errors, but not all `Throwable`s are non recoverable. If error is non recoverable the appliation is going to hell anyway, so why should I care. I do not handle any data that could be lost.

Comment: I mentioned that to make sure you're (and whoever else might read this question) is aware of this fact.

Comment: @TomášZato `Throwable` is the parent class of `Error` and `Exception`. Name an `Error` that you hope to recover from. Never `catch Throwable` and never `throw Throwable` - this class should not appear anywhere in your code. Ever.

Comment: @BoristheSpider NoSuchMethod error thrown in reflection is one that is actually quite harmless. It could even theoretically happen in one part of my code thought at that particular place it is caught and handled.